# regex matching leading trailing and intermediate text

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use regex in c# to find this text:

```
gt;gt; ssssss cccc=SpellE>OwnerName ssssss lt;lt;
```

in this text:

```
gt;gt; ssssss cccc=SpellE>OwnerName ssssss lt;lt;

gt;gt; ssssss cccc=SpellE>RenterName ssssss lt;lt;
```

I used this regex:

```
\[gt\;gt\;\](.*)[OwnerName](.*)\[lt\;lt\;\]
```

but it finds both phrases not just the one that contains RenterName

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? Why not just `if (thestring.Contains("gt;gt; ssssss cccc=SpellE>OwnerName ssssss lt;lt;")) { ..`?

Comment: Please look at the syntax for Regex. Anything between `[` and `]` will match **any one character** between those square brackets.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  The ssssss and cccccc can be anything.or nothing.  Specifically I want to match if it has OwnerName between gt;gt;, and lt;lt; but doesn't contain gt;gt; or lt;lt; within the bounding endpoints.  It should not match "gt;gt; xxxxx gt;gt; yyyy OwnerName zzz lt;lt;", but it should match "gt;gt; yyyy OwnerName zzz lt;lt;".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
(?:gt;){2}((?>(?!gt;).)*)(OwnerName)((?>(?!lt;).)*)(?:lt;){2}
```

This regex has 2 specific parts: `(?>(?!gt;).)*` matches any text that has no `gt;` and `(?>(?!lt;).)*` matches any text that has no `lt;`. I see no need in `^`/`$` anchors if you use this regex.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Agt%3B)%7B2%7D((%3F%3E(%3F!gt%3B).)*)(OwnerName)((%3F%3E(%3F!lt%3B).)*)(%3F%3Alt%3B)%7B2%7D&i=gt%3Bgt%3B%20ssssss%20cccc%3DSpellE%3EOwnerName%20ssssss%20lt%3Blt%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Agt%3Bgt%3B%20ssssss%20cccc%3DSpellE%3ERenterName%20ssssss%20lt%3Blt%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AIt%20should%20not%20match%20%0D%0Agt%3Bgt%3B%20xxxxx%20gt%3Bgt%3B%20yyyy%20OwnerName%20zzz%20lt%3Blt%3B%0D%0AIt%20should%20match%20%0D%0Agt%3Bgt%3B%20yyyy%20OwnerName%20zzz%20lt%3Blt%3B)

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/bM7hP8/1 - try this: `gt\;gt\;(.*)(OwnerName)(.*)lt\;lt\;`

it catches only the OwnerName sequence.

And if you want the whole sequence, wrap it like so: `(gt\;gt\;(.*)(OwnerName)(.*)lt\;lt\;)`

Answer (score 0):

try this : `^(gt\;){2}(.*)(OwnerName)(.*)(lt\;){2}$`
it works fine.
This regex only matches `gt;gt; ssssss cccc=SpellE>OwnerName ssssss lt;lt;` .

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!